# Video/Audio Streaming over WebSockets/TCP

Tags: javascript, audio, video, websocket, streaming

does anyone know how to stream video from the webcam and microphone via HTML5 to a websocket, and reconstuct it on another client? I have looked at a couple of possible solutions, such as WebRTC and MediaRecorder, but so far I have encountered issues with both:

- WebRTC is P2P, which raises privacy concerns, since the peers' public IPs are exposed
- MediaRecorder gives chunked data in the `ondataavailable` callback, meaning that to reconstruct the data you need to have no packet loss (using `start()` and `stop()` to obtain segments yields low quality audio as there are cuts between each segment, and increasing segment size will increase delay between clients)

I have looked for possible solutions/implementations, however, there is no clear resource that explains how this is to be done.

Comment: There is an API for low-latency bidirectional streaming, [WebRTC][1]. It is intended not only for P2P connections but for Peer2Server as SFU's and MCU's (see this [post][2])


  [1]: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API
  [2]: https://getstream.io/blog/what-is-a-selective-forwarding-unit-in-webrtc/

Comment: @alphα is there any implementation/documentation available out there on how to write an SFU, preferrably in nodejs?

Comment: If you don't have a lot of experience with WebRTC you don't want to code an SFU server from scratch, you can use 3rd party libraries or modules to help you with that. See Kurento, Mediasoup, Janus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, thank you!
I'll check out Kurento, Mediasoup, Janus and see what they have to offer.